# Loopback 4 establish rest api root (equivalent restApiRoot in config loopback 3)

Tags: loopbackjs, v4l2loopback

In loopback 3, we could set "restApiRoot" in the server config in order to prepend our api calls with some url (ie '/api')  Is there some sort of way to do this in loopback 4?  The [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Server.html#rest-options) for the bundled REST server seems to have a port/protocol option, but nothing about api root.

Comment: Did you find a way for it. I had the same query and about to ask question...

Comment: No I didn't @VISHALDAGA.  Ended up reverting to loopback 3 until lb4 is feature equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ability to configure REST API root path will be released in the next version of LoopBack 4, hopefully in the next few days.

The pull request: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/pull/2097

Cross-posting from the documentation:

Sometime it's desirable to expose REST endpoints using a base path, such as
`/api`. The base path can be set as part of the RestServer configuration.

```js
const app = new RestApplication({
  rest: {
    basePath: '/api',
  },
});
```

The `RestApplication` and `RestServer` both provide a `basePath()` API:

```js
const app: RestApplication;
// ...
app.basePath('/api');
```

With the `basePath`, all REST APIs and static assets are served on URLs starting
with the base path.